# Will pre-sorting smaller chunks of a large numpy.array make sorting the whole array faster?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have a very large array of values that I am sorting. The array size is ~ `(1e9, 3)` in `float16` i.e. `dtype='f2'` in `numpy`. So when it is built and sitting there, it takes about 6GB of memory.

I then sort this large array, which runs the memory up 3-4x that level for reasons I don't quite understand. The formula I use to sort it (which should only make a single temporary copy of one column of the array from what I can gather), is the following:

`arr = arr[arr[:,idx].argsort()]`

This sort works and doesn't blow up my memory to the point of crashing, though it does spill into virtual memory (I have 16GB memory luckily).

My question is this: the large array is actually composed of 22 smaller arrays that are concatenated together in a sub-function. Is there anything to be gained from pre-sorting each smaller array before building the large array and sorting THAT?

Comment: Your title asks whether the pre-sorting will make the big sort *faster*, but your question talks about memory usage.  Are you trying to make the sort faster, make it use less memory, or both?

Comment: What sorting algorithm are you using ?

Comment: Have a look at this : http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: @BrenBarn I am mostly interested in whether the sorting will speed up if it is less "randomized" basically. But memory improvements would be useful as well, since I will be using a computer cluster where memory costs money :)

Comment: @Onilol I am pretty sure the default is merge sort in `numpy.argsort()`

Comment: If you happen to pre-sort your input maybe shell sort would be better

Comment: @Onilol: The question (at least as I understand it) is about whether it will speed up numpy's sorting.  Writing your own sort algorithm is outside the scope of this.

Comment: Ok.. considering numpy.argsort uses merge sort.. You would be basically saving a step in it so yeah.. you would gain some performance.

Comment: The default sorting algorithm in numpy is quicksort. You can set it to one of `'quicksort'`, `'mergesort'` or `'heapsort'` with the `kind` keyword argument.  The extra memory comes from the indexing array, made of 32 or 64 bit integers, depending on your build, and the copy of the full array that is done when indexing it with the results of `argsort`.  And the only way to be sure about performance benefits of pre-sorting is by going ahead and measuring it.  I'd be surprised if you gained much.